# closing a window, Redirecting  to old page after a login [client side prog]

Tags: api, redirect, youtube, oauth-2.0, client-side

I am working with youtube api so using the Oauth 2.0 for client side authorization.

> https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Client_Side_Web_Applications_Flow

when clicking login opens a new window for authorization with google oauth 2.0, and gets redirected, it opens the redirected Url in new window (that was used for authorization), how do after login/whether successful or failure, i close the login window and go back to original site with the token and results.

If you are gonna suggest a session variable to implement this, i think with client side programming approach this wont be possible.

I need a similar login/authorization approach as here:

> http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html
>   I tried to decipher the code, but it dint work out.

I would prefer a client side approach as the thing i plan to work on is purely client driven (JS)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is probably HTML5 postMessage.

However, I have a workable method using standard JavaScript and `window.opener` in my *Getting Started with OAuth 2.0* book (published by O'Reilly).  This works fine in recent browsers:

I have a page called `oauth2callback.html`.  This page is your `redirect_uri`.  It parses the access token out of the `#` hash fragment in the URL, calls a JS function in the `window.opener` to set the access token and then closes itself:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var oauthParams = {};

// parse the query string
// from http://oauthssodemo.appspot.com/step/2
var params = {}, queryString = location.hash.substring(1),
    regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;
while (m = regex.exec(queryString)) {
  oauthParams[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
}

window.opener.setOauthParams(oauthParams);
window.opener.callApi();
window.close();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The parent page (which kicks off the entire process by opening up the OAuth flow in a popup) has a simple JavaScript function called `setOauthParams` which accepts the params and stores them in a global variable:

```
function setOauthParams(oauthParamsPassed) {
  this.oauthParams = oauthParamsPassed;
}
```

I have other code which kicks off the OAuth flow and uses jQuery to call the API (Google Contacts in my case), but it doesn't sound like you need that.